# Diamond Using For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am attempting to have a diamond print out based on user input using for loops. I've gotten it to print out the right side of the diamond but can't get it to print out the left side. I've tried reversing my code to no avail. I'm having trouble figuring out the logic to have my code print out an entire diamond. Thanks in advance!

The expected output if num=2 is (without the lines, of course):

```
 *
*$*
 *
```

Here's my code so far:

```
//Print out a diamond shape based on user input
for (int i=num; i>0; --i){
    System.out.print("*");
    for (int n=i; n<num; ++n){
        System.out.print("$*");
    }//Ending bracket of nested for loop
    System.out.println();
}//Ending bracket of for loop
//Print out a diamond shape based on user input
for (int i=0; i<num; ++i){
    System.out.print("*");
    for (int n=i; n<num; ++n){
        System.out.print("$*");
    }//Ending bracket of nested for loop
    System.out.println();
}//Ending bracket of for loop
```

Comment: Could you post the expected output?

Comment: @Tunaki if num=2 the expected output is:

__*__
_*$*_
__*__

Comment: Can you [edit] that into the question?

Comment: @Tunaki, I've attempted to edit it into the question but it isn't formatting properly. If num=2 the format needs to be one asterisk on top, asterisk dollar sign asterisk in the middle, and one asterisk on the bottom

Comment: analyze the lines you need to print, e.g. https://gist.github.com/zapl/2c5bb95e93a5e248acb2deefcf22e168 then think about a loop that can do that

Comment: @zapl, I've done that. I know what lines I need to print and how they need to be formatted. I just don't know how to go about programming it properly.

Comment: @SMcGwier could you also include a larger case, like n=4 or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically only need to add another loop (one for the top half and one for the bottom half) in which you add enough spaces on each line in order to center the diamond:

```
for (int i=num; i>0; --i){
    //Insert spaces in order to center the diamond
    for (int n=0; n<i; ++n){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("*");
    for (int n=i; n<num; ++n){
        System.out.print("$*");
    }//Ending bracket of nested for loop
    System.out.println();
}//Ending bracket of for loop
//Print out a diamond shape based on user input
for (int i=0; i<=num; ++i){   //<= to print the last asterisk
    //Insert spaces in order to center the diamond
    for (int n=0; n<i; ++n){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("*");
    for (int n=i; n<num; ++n){
        System.out.print("$*");
    }//Ending bracket of nested for loop
    System.out.println();
}//Ending bracket of for loop
```

I'm not sure about the logic of the correlation between `num` and the shape of the diamond in your example. My code prints your desired diamond for `num = 1` not `num = 2`. So in this code `num` determines the maximum width of the diamond (the number of `$` signs). So `num = 2` prints:

```
  *
 *$*
*$*$*
 *$*
  *
```

If you want

```
 *
*$*
 *
```

for `num=1` and so on, you can simply replace every occurence of `num` with `num-1` in the code above. Alternatively, you could also just add the line

```
num--;
```

before the code and leave the rest as it is.

Comment: AWESOME! However, when I run the code it doesn't print out the last asterisk for the last line (it's been doing that since the beginning). Do you know why that is and how to correct it?

Comment: Did you copy the complete code or just the inner loops? My version should print the last asterisk because I changed the condition of the second main loop to `i <= n` instead of `i < n`. Forgot to mention that in the answer.

Comment: I completely missed that. Thank you so, so much for your help! I kept thinking it was something more difficult than the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm to late to get the answer, Keiwan beat me. But here is a loop from scratch. Perhaps its still useful to you or someone else. I also was unable to figure out what num was used for, so I used it as the amount of layers from the center.

```
// The number variable.
int num = 2;    // Num is used to specify the amount of layers.
// used variables
int size = num * 2 + 1; // total size of the diamond.
int i;  // row
int j;  // col
int a;  // amount to draw
int s;  // start to draw
if (num == 0) {
    // The diamond has a thickness of 0, only print the center
    System.out.print("$");
} else if (num >= 1) {
    // the diamond has a thickness of at least 1.
    for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
            if (i == num + 1 && j == num + 1) {
                // We are in the center, print the $ and continue
                System.out.print("$");
                continue;
            } else {
                if (i <= num + 1) {
                    // amount is row times 2 minus one
                    a = i * 2 - 1;
                } else {
                    // Inverted: amount is (size minus row plus 1) times two minus one
                    a = (size - i + 1 ) * 2 - 1;
                }
                // starting point is (thickness plus one) minus (amount divided by two)
                s = (int)((num + 1) - (a / 2));
                // if col is bigger or equals start and col is less or equals start plus amount minus one
                if (j >= s && j <= s + a - 1) {
                    // print a "#";
                    System.out.print("#");
                } else {
                    // we are not suppose to print, print a space.
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        // reached the end of the line, begin on a new lie
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Output of: num = 1;

```
 # 
#$#
 #
```

Output of: num = 2;

```
  #  
 ### 
##$##
 ### 
  #
```

Output of: num = 15;

```
               #               
              ###              
             #####             
            #######            
           #########           
          ###########          
         #############         
        ###############        
       #################       
      ###################      
     #####################     
    #######################    
   #########################   
  ###########################  
 ############################# 
###############$###############
 ############################# 
  ###########################  
   #########################   
    #######################    
     #####################     
      ###################      
       #################       
        ###############        
         #############         
          ###########          
           #########           
            #######            
             #####             
              ###              
               #
```

EDIT: 1 Small edit in the comments of the source (typos)